# Operating system that show only one page and without explorer

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, web-operating-system

I want to find an operating system or program that show only one page on the internet. And disable any other functions like an explorer.

For example, the system opens only one page but other functions, pages, explorer are disabled.

How can I do that?

Comment: Try searching for "browser in kiosk mode"

Comment: How to disable explorer, and prevent edit browser properties

Comment: For Chrome see this: https://superuser.com/questions/716426/running-latest-chrome-for-windows-in-kiosk-mode